# Names of gnome-shell power-off/restart/logout dialogs

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, css

In the latest versions of gnome-shell the power-off/restart dialog has been split into separate dialogs (compare Ubuntu 20.04 with 21.10).  Along with the log-out dialog they are all themed by the entries for end-session-dialog in gnome-shell.css.  Do the individual dialogs have names so that they can be themed independently, e.g. the last-child could have a different background color in each?

To make my intentions clear, here are images of what I would like to have.  In each case it's the background color of the last child that is different.  With just the end-session-dialog modified all three dialogs will have the same background color for each component.

[image: Power Off Dialog]

[image: Restart Dialog]

[image: Log Out Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging, and currently (2023.01.11) it seems there are no such names.

You could possibly extend it with an additional `class`, if You have the time and some JavaScript knowledge.

You can check for Yourself, here is the file that is responsible for all of them: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/js/ui/endSessionDialog.js#L232

- Line 232: `styleClass: 'end-session-dialog',` might be a good example/starting point, as it adds the base class to the dialog.
- Line 712: `async OpenAsync(parameters, invocation) {` seems to be the entry point, so that might be another plce to start looking.

If You make it, do a merge request if You please, so that others can make use of it too.